# Docker - How to check Docker container logs real-time update in terminal?

Tags: docker, terminal, docker-container

I have a docker container running with detach mode (-d) flag. This container running application which is updating some output/logs in the terminal.

I want to see those output from the container in real-time in the terminal.

Is there any way possible to see the docker logs in terminal at real-time update from the application?

Thanks.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You need to tell Docker to follow the log output:

```
$ docker logs -f CONTAINER_NAME
```

Comment: Thank you so much. It is working as I expected. This "-f" flag solved this issue.

Answer (score 0):

https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/logs/

```
$ docker logs [OPTIONS] CONTAINER
```